# Polyfill for location.replace()

Tags: javascript, dom, browser-history

In a single page app, I have a requirement where I have to remove the current page from the browser history. My solution to use:

> location.replace(url) **Description form MDN documentation:**
>
> Replace the current document with the one at the provided URL. The 
>   difference from the assign() method is that after using replace() the 
>   current page will not be saved in session history, meaning the user 
>   won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to it.

The solution works on most browsers but breaks on Webkit version of Blackberry 6.0. My question is are there any polyfill's or workaround I can code to mimick this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Did some research around it and according to Documentation in MDN:

> For security reasons the History object doesn't allow the
>   non-privileged code to access the URLs of other pages in the session
>   history,but it does allow it to navigate the session history.

Given that you can't really access the History Object from non-privileged code I don't think there is much you can do to in-terms of creating a polyfill for broswers that don't support location.replace().